# Vuex actions: access action within other action (no dispatch, need to chain Promise.all)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Within vuex action I need to wait for results of several other actions (all promises). I would like to avoid nesting dispatches, is there a way to do it by using Promise.all? Eg:

```
Promise.all([ action1, action2 ])
    .then(() => { 
        // do the thing
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actions return Promises - then yes, you can do that.
For example

```
let res1 = this.$store.dispatch('action1', data1);
let res2 = this.$store.dispatch('action2', data2);

Promise.all([ res1, res2 ])
    .then(() => { 
        // do the thing
    });

const actions = 
{
  action1 ({ commit, getters, rootState })
  {
    return this.$axios.get(`/user/patient/${rootState.route.params.id}/call/currentCall`)
      .then(res =>
      {
        let call = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(res.data).length === 0 ? false : res.data;
        if (call && call.call_details.patient_dial_status === 'in-progress')
        {
          commit('setCurrentCall', {
            currentCall: call,
            callState: 'in-call'
          });
        }
        return Promise.resolve(call);
      });
  }, 
};
```

Comment: I see. Assigning dispatch to a variable seemed counter-intuitive, since the promise would execute immediately, before Promise.all is reached. Thanks!

Comment: The action returns a Promise (created by Axios) and this promise is then resolved inside the `success` handler of the Axios call - so `Promise.all` simply waits until both promises have been resolved.